# Issue with Geofences - addGeofence() not 'working'?

Tags: android, android-geofence

I'm Having an issue with creating a list of Geofences. Within my onCreate method I have a for loop which calls createGeofence() and createGeoFenceRequest(). Within createGeofenceRequest, the builder should use the addGeofence method which then calls createGeoFencePendingIntent(). My Stack Trace is showing that on createGeofence() and createGeofenceRequest() are being called but nothing else.

Also the current location marker I am trying to create is not showing on the map.

I am following this tutorial and trying to add my own tweaks

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639

To be honest I'm very lost, I'm quite new to android and there is not much of this code I grasp. Apologies if I haven't supplied enough info but if more is needed I will add it.

Here is my code:

LoggedInActivity

```
package com.mad.losesano2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class LoggedInActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        LocationListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

    private static GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final long MIN_TIME = 400;
    private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;

    private GoogleMap map;

    private ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Store> store_objects = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);


        createGoogleApi();
        store_objects = (ArrayList<Store>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stores_objects");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            for (Store store : store_objects) {


                Geofence geofence = createGeofence(store.getStoreID(), store.getLatitude(), store.getLongitude());
                mGeofenceList.add(geofence);
                createGeofenceRequest(geofence);


            }

        }

    private Geofence createGeofence( int id, double lat, double longi ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(Integer.toString(id))
                .setCircularRegion( lat, longi, 5)
                .setExpirationDuration(864000000)
                .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
                .build();
    }

    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
                .addGeofence( geofence )
                .build();
    }

    private void createGoogleApi() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
        if ( googleApiClient == null ) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                    .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
                    .addApi( LocationServices.API )
                    .build();
        }
    }

    private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
    private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;

    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        if ( geoFencePendingIntent != null )
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenceTransitionService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    }

    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    googleApiClient,
                    request,
                    createGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
        getLastKnownLocation();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick("+latLng +")");
        markerForGeofence(latLng);
    }


    private Marker locationMarker;
    private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation("+latLng+")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title);
        if ( map!=null ) {
            // Remove the anterior marker
            if ( locationMarker != null )
                locationMarker.remove();
            locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            float zoom = 14f;
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }

    private Marker geoFenceMarker;
    // Create a marker for the geofence creation
    private void markerForGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerForGeofence("+latLng+")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        // Define marker options
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                .title(title);
        if ( map!=null ) {
            // Remove last geoFenceMarker
            if (geoFenceMarker != null)
                geoFenceMarker.remove();

            geoFenceMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged ["+location+"]");
        lastLocation = location;
        writeActualLocation(location);
    }
    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
        if ( checkPermission() ) {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if ( lastLocation != null ) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                        "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                        " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
                writeLastLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("LoSeSANO", "Permissions needed");
        }
    }
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =  1000;
    private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 900;
    private void startLocationUpdates(){
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if ( checkPermission() )
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
    private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {
        markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }
    private void writeLastLocation() {
        writeActualLocation(lastLocation);
    }
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
        // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
        if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
            drawGeofence();
        }
    }

    private Circle geoFenceLimits;
    private void drawGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawGeofence()");

        if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
            geoFenceLimits.remove();

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center( geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
                .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
                .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
                .radius( 5 );
        geoFenceLimits = map.addCircle( circleOptions );
    }

    static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context geofenceService, String msg)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,msg);
        return new Intent(geofenceService,MainActivity.class);
    }


}
```

GeofenceTransitionService

```
    package com.mad.losesano2;


        import android.app.IntentService;
        import android.app.Notification;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.util.Log;

        import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
        import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
        import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

public class GeofenceTransitionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GeofenceTransitionService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    public GeofenceTransitionService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
            String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
            Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
            return;
        }

        int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

            sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
        }
    }


    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
            triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
        }

        String status = null;
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
            status = "Entering ";
        else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            status = "Exiting ";
        return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
    }

    private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

        // Intent to start the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = LoggedInActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
                getApplicationContext(), msg
        );

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        // Creating and sending Notification
        NotificationManager notificatioMng =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificatioMng.notify(
                GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

    }

    // Create notification
    private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }


    private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GeoFence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "Too many GeoFences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "Too many pending intents";
            default:
                return "Unknown error.";
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
05-01 13:41:18.948 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: onActivityCreated
05-01 13:41:18.949 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=12726, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignupActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6720222596079632252}]
05-01 13:41:18.998 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-01 13:41:19.006 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-01 13:41:19.006 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 42701370
05-01 13:41:19.019 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SignupActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-6720222596079632252, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=StoreListRegisterActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6720222596079632251}]
05-01 13:41:19.062 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-01 13:41:19.293 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 D/FA: Connected to remote service
05-01 13:41:19.293 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
05-01 13:41:19.304 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:22.146 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3139
05-01 13:41:22.148 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 42704509
05-01 13:41:22.151 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=3139, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=StoreListRegisterActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6720222596079632251}]
05-01 13:41:22.159 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: onActivityCreated
05-01 13:41:22.202 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
05-01 13:41:22.211 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:219
05-01 13:41:22.212 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 219
05-01 13:41:22.262 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
05-01 13:41:22.297 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11910000
05-01 13:41:22.302 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 12529024
05-01 13:41:22.580 7820-7991/com.mad.losesano2 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-01 13:41:22.614 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGoogleApi()
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofence
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofenceRequest
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofence
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofenceRequest
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofence
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofenceRequest
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofence
05-01 13:41:22.618 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: createGeofenceRequest
05-01 13:41:22.631 7820-7826/com.mad.losesano2 I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=450KB, data=345KB
05-01 13:41:22.632 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 42704996
05-01 13:41:22.633 7820-7826/com.mad.losesano2 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=449KB, data=291KB
05-01 13:41:22.636 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=StoreListRegisterActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-6720222596079632251, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoggedInActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6720222596079632250}]
05-01 13:41:22.726 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:22.731 7820-8014/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa4efc540: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
05-01 13:41:22.766 7820-8014/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa4efc540: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xa4f2a700)
05-01 13:41:22.789 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:22.832 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:22.860 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:22.866 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: onConnected()
05-01 13:41:22.867 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: getLastKnownLocation()
05-01 13:41:22.867 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: checkPermission()
05-01 13:41:22.878 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: LasKnown location. Long: 6.3433983 | Lat: 5.432
05-01 13:41:22.878 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:41:22.878 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: startLocationUpdates()
05-01 13:41:22.879 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: checkPermission()
05-01 13:41:22.931 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:22.948 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x94336080 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa7b03f00
05-01 13:41:22.959 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=20 et=+11h51m45s283ms alt=0.0 vAcc=40 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:41:22.959 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:41:22.975 7820-7848/com.mad.losesano2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7b05720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa7b03370)
05-01 13:41:23.292 7820-7826/com.mad.losesano2 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=495KB, data=330KB
05-01 13:41:23.293 7820-7826/com.mad.losesano2 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=485KB, data=324KB
05-01 13:41:23.293 7820-7826/com.mad.losesano2 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
05-01 13:41:24.621 7820-8016/com.mad.losesano2 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
05-01 13:41:24.627 7820-8016/com.mad.losesano2 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
05-01 13:41:24.627 7820-8016/com.mad.losesano2 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
05-01 13:41:24.632 7820-8016/com.mad.losesano2 W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
05-01 13:41:27.689 7820-7911/com.mad.losesano2 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
05-01 13:41:31.442 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h51m53s799ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:41:31.442 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:41:41.438 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h52m3s799ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:41:41.438 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:41:51.437 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h52m13s799ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:41:51.437 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:42:01.438 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h52m23s799ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:42:01.438 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:42:11.437 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h52m33s799ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:42:11.437 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:42:21.444 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h52m43s800ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:42:21.444 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:42:31.439 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h52m53s801ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:42:31.440 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:42:41.439 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h53m3s800ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:42:41.439 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:42:51.445 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h53m13s803ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:42:51.446 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:43:01.439 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h53m23s801ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:43:01.439 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
05-01 13:43:11.440 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 D/MainActivity: onLocationChanged [Location[fused 5.432000,6.343398 hAcc=23 et=+11h53m33s802ms alt=0.0 vAcc=47 sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=52]}]]
05-01 13:43:11.441 7820-7820/com.mad.losesano2 I/MainActivity: markerLocation(lat/lng: (5.432,6.3433983))
```

Answer (score 0):

`createGeoFencePendingIntent` is not called at all. In addition you say "Within `createGeofenceRequest`, the builder should use the `addGeofence` method", but the `addGeofence` method is not what you defined but the builder one.